How to concat multiple lazyframe created from numpy ndarray and datetime.datetime in Polars
I wish to convert this snipper of pandas code into polars code to learn polars and see if I can benefit w.r.t speed performances:
df_list = []
for datum in data:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    temp_data = datum.data # list of tuples of numpy ndarray
    df["A"] = temp_data[1].ravel().astype(np.float32)
    df["B"] = temp_data[2].ravel().astype(np.float32)
    df["C"] = datum.analDate # datetime.datetime
    df["D"] = datum.validDate.replace(hour=int(datum.validityTime/100))
    for name in names:
        df[name] = temp_data[0].ravel().astype(np.float32)  
    df_list.append(df)          
df = pd.concat(df_list)
df['E'] = df['C'].dt.hour

The idea is that I have many files in a custom binary format. After reading them with a custom reader, I can access some of those fields which are either numpy ndarray or datetime.datetime. I wish to iterate the files and save them into a list, and at the end concatenate them together lazily.
Being new to Polars I wish to understand:

The best way to create Polars dateframe from that memory without copy data if possible.
How to deal with "broadcasting". For instance, considering columns C and D. Do I have to create a list with a single datetime.datetime instance and multiple it by the lenght of the other columns?
How to deal with duplicate columns name. For instance name may be a duplicate in names. How does Polars manage it?


You can start by looking at https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.from_numpy.html and https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.lazy.html.
For your example I can give you a little snippet of what you can try.
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df_list = []
for datum in data:
    temp_data = datum.data


    A = pl.Series(temp_data[1].ravel().astype(np.float32))
    B = pl.Series(temp_data[2].ravel().astype(np.float32))
    C = pl.Series(temp_data[0].ravel().astype(np.int64))
    D = pl.Series(np.array([datum.validDate.replace(hour=int(datum.validityTime/100))], dtype=np.int64))

    df = pl.DataFrame(
        {"A": A, "B": B, "C": pl.datetime(C), "D": pl.datetime(D)}
    )

    for name in names:
        df[name] = pl.Series(temp_data[0].ravel().astype(np.float32))

    df_list.append(df)

You might have to debug it a little based on the exact data you have, I am just guessing based on what you wrote above.
Would be good if you can provide some examples of the data you are reading and trying to concatenate.
Then you can try concatenating the date using df = pl.lazy.concat(df_list).
And you can try broadcasting datetime using the hour method df = df.with_column(pl.col("C").hour().alias("E")).

pl.from_numpy does copy data unfortunately

@Luca check out my answer, this shouldnt make a copy
